# Is a function differentiable on a punctured interval differentiable on the whole interval?

Tags: real-analysis

Q:If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on all $t\in(a,b)\setminus\{x\}$, and $\lim_{t \to x} f'(t)$ exists, then f is differentiable at $x$ and $f'(x)= \lim_{t \to x} f'(t)$.

I just need a small hint to keep me going on (no solution please). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of $f'(x)$ and the mean value theorem on the interval from $x$ to $t$, for $t$ sufficiently close to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the mean value theorem

Answer (score 0):

For $h=t-x \ne 0$, write 
$$
f(x)=f(t-h)=f(t)-hf'(t)+h\phi_t(h),
$$
where $\phi_t(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$. Then
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{f(t-h)-f(t)}{-h}=f'(t)-\phi_t(h).
$$