# A derivative problem

Tags: derivatives, continuity

> Let $a<c<b,  f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Assume $f$ is differentiable at every point of $(a,b) \backslash \{c\}$ and $f'$ has a limit at $c$. Then which of the following are true?
>
> 1)$f$ is differentiable at $c$.
>
> 2)$f$ need not be differentiable at $c$.
>
> 3)$f$ is differentiable at $c$ but $f'(c)$ is not necessarily  $\lim_{x \to c}f'(x)$.
>
> 4) $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and  $\lim_{x \to c}f'(x)=f'(c)$.

Since $f$ is given to be continuous everywhere and is differentiable at every point except at $c$, I feel option 1) is correct, hence 2) is false.

How to look at 3) and 4)?

Comment: With "$f'$ has a limit point at $c$", you mean that $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$ exists?

Comment: but....can the limit $\lim_{x \to c} f'(x)$ be different from $f'(c)$?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen yes....I corrected the same

Comment: @Naman: The answers to the question that I linked to show that (4) holds. – Also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/221273/42969 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/169157/42969 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257907/42969

Answer (score 0):

Note that corners and cusps are out of the question because either would produce a jump discontinuity (of finite length) in the image of $f'$. The remaining options of both a removable discontinuity or a hyperbolic portion are both plausible since they both preserve the notion of at limit at $c$ [keep in mind that the hyperbola would preserve the limit if of odd degree]. This should help you answer your question.