# Problem on derivative, which of the following are correct?[CSIR-JUNE-2019]

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $a<c<b$, $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Assume that $f$ is differentiable at every point of $(a,b)\setminus\{c\}$ and $f'$ has a limit at $c$. Then Which of the following are correct?

(A) $f$ is differentiable at $c$.

(B) $f$ need not be differentiable at $c$

(C) $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)=f'(c)$

(D) $f$ is differentiable at $c$ but $f'(c)$ is not necessorily $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$

Here, $\lim_{x\to c^+}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to c^-}f'(x)=L$(given). I tried to draw a curve satisfying this with sharp points(My aim is to show that $f$ need not be differentiable). But not able to find. So, $f$ is differentiable at $c$. But I am not able to prove analytically.

Comment: A and C are correct.

Comment: How? Can you give hints for analytic proof?

Comment: $(a,b)\setminus\{c\}$ what does this meant?

Comment: set difference. Interval without a point $c$

Comment: (C) is correct (so obviously (A) is also correct). TO see why, apply the mean value theorem

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/221273/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/169157/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257907/42969.

Comment: And the same question was asked recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3264432/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, there is $k_c\in (a,c)$ s.t. $$\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}=f'(k_c).$$

If $L:=\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$, then $$f'_{\text{left}}(c)=\lim_{x\to c^-}\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}=L.$$

Do as well on $(c,b)$ and you'll get that $$f_{\text{right}}'(c)=f'_{\text{left}}(c)=L.$$

Comment: So, (A) and (C) are correct. right? Thank you very much. :)

Comment: yes (as it was said in the comments).